# How to make an empty sequence in common lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

A function takes a sequence as the parameter. In the function, I want to make an empty sequence of the same type of the parameter. Then I'll store something and return it such that the return type is the same as the parameter. But

(make-sequence (type-of *parameter*) **0**)  will cause error if *parameter* is any list or vector of some length.

My current solution is:
1. use an empty list to store things, let's call it temp-list
2. (make-sequence (type-of *parameter*) (length temp-list))
3. copy the elements, then return

Other better solutions?

Comment: sounds a bit confused, you can't use PUSH with sequences - though with lists. Maybe you need to show us your code???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

returning an empty sequence of the same type

```
(subseq sequence 0 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's failing because type-of a list is CONS, not LIST, and type-of a vector has its size, which you're trying to override.

You could convert the type-of by some simple rules, like:

```
(cond ((eq x 'cons) 'list)
      ((consp x) (car x))))
```

But PUSH doesn't really work on vectors, so I'm not sure what you'd want to do there, anyway: you'll need a list for the consing, and then to convert, anyway, right?

Comment: Oh, yeah, PUSH working with vectores is not like that with lists. Thanks. But there are still other functions to store things in vector. The Rainer's answer satisfy the need.